# Adding QTY+Location to order view page, Demac Magento-Multi-Location-Inventory Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, multistore, column, locations

DemacMedia Magento-Multi-Location-Inventory extension installed to 1.9.2.4 store. Working good and mass stock upload is also working

Added picture to show module and explaining what I want to do.

https://github.com/DemacMedia/Magento-Multi-Location-Inventory

It is showing Multi-Location QTY info only inside of Edit Product Page

I tried many things to put Location+QTY info to **Order view page (sales_order/view/order)**

Tried to add variation of below data to

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml

but nothing changed. I want see below data (location+qty) at view order page.

```
$this->getLocationsInventories() as $_location)

$_location['code'], $_location['qty']
```

Below code is original Multi-location file of module.

> app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\demac\catalog_multilocationinventory.phtml

```
<?php foreach ($this->getLocationsInventories() as $_location): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $_location['name'] ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text"
                                   name="multilocationinventory[<?php echo $_location['id'] ?>][quantity]"
                                   class="input-text validate-number"
                                   <?php echo ($_location['manage_stock'] === "1") ? '' : 'style="visibility:hidden;"' ?>
                                   value="<?php echo $_location['qty'] ?>"/>
                        </td>
```

[image: Catalog/Manage Product + Order View Picture]

Answer (score 0):

add this before table add this

> /public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/qty.phtml

```
  <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku(), array('Id'));
    $locationStockCollection = Mage::getModel('demac_multilocationinventory/location')->getCollection();
    $locationStockCollection->joinStockDataOnProductAndStoreView($product->getId(), 1);
    $locations = array();
        foreach ($locationStockCollection as $locationStock) { ?>
        <tr>
    <?php if ($locationStock->getQty()>0){?>
        <td><? echo $locationStock['name'];?> </td>
        <td><strong><? echo floatval($locationStock->getQty());?> </strong></td>
    <?php } ?>

     </tr>
     <?php 
    }
?>
```